# Как сделать переменную Button внутри евента глобальной?

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем привет! Мне при написании на tkinter столкнулся с проблей из которой не могу сделать евент в евенте. То есть у меня есть одна главная кнопка, которая запускает евент и в  этом евенте появляется новая кнопка, которая опять же запускает новый евент, но при этом он должгна уничтожить кнопку прошлого евента, но у меня так не получается. Помогите пожалуйста. Снизу привел пример.

```
def vibor_category(event): #первый ивент
    btn_start.destroy()
    vibor_kategory=Label(root,text='Выберите категорию слов:',font=15)
    vibor_kategory.pack(fill='both')
    slova_sport=Button(root,text='Спорт')
    slova_sport.bind("<Button-2>",deadsport) # Кнопка которую хочу уничтожить в другом ивенте
    slova_sport.pack(fill='both')
def deadsport():
    sport_words=['футбол','волейбол','баскетбол','аут','крикет']
    word=random.choice(sport_words)
    resh=list('_'*len(word))
    slova_sport.destroy() #попытка уничтожения кнопки
    vivod_text=Label(root,text=resh)
btn_start=Button(root, 
                 text='Играть',
                 width=30,height=10,
                 bg='white',fg='black',)
btn_start.bind("<Button-1>", dead_game_start) #кнопка запускающая ивент
btn_start.pack(fill='both')
root.
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Добавьте минимально воспроизводимый код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что переменная slova_sport, которую вы пытаетесь уничтожить в функции deadsport, не видна в этой функции, так как она определена в функции vibor_category. Чтобы исправить это, вам нужно сделать slova_sport глобальной переменной или передать ее в функцию deadsport

Comment: Я сделал так как ты сказал, но появилась новая проблема. Оказывается дело было не в глобальности переменной, а в чем-то другом. Я пытаюсь удалить кнопку, а она тупо не удаляется

Comment: у вас функция deadsport завершается сразу после уничтожения кнопки, и поэтому вы не видите изменений. Чтобы увидеть изменения, вам нужно добавить цикл событий Tkinter (root.update() и root.update_idletasks()) после уничтожения кнопки. Простите что так долго ждали ответа

Comment: Ничего страшного, главное что помогли